# Update Oracle database from Different sheet on multiple servers

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I need to some advise. I want to update one oracle database from different sheet on multiple servers. When these sheet gets updated then Oracle database which is installed on other servers got updated automatic. Sheet may be different types.

Comment: I don't quite understand what those "sheets" are; the most usual meaning (from my point if view) is "Microsoft Excel worksheets", but I'm not sure that that's what you are talking about. Could you explain it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My requirement is When any sheet such that CSV, PDF and may be different type sheet which is locate on different server. I want when these sheet got update then My oracle database which is on different server will be updated.

Comment: Create an external table..